# Getting error while inserting blob datatype value into mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I am trying to enter data into mysql table Fruitbox .But while entering data I am getting error **Fruitpdf cannot be null**. I created fruitbox table as follows:

```
Fruitname(varchar(100), Fruitpdf(blob), Fruitprice(int)
```

Fruitpdf column contains pdf files of fruit. My file mango.pdf in desktop is size of 190 KB.

I wrote following query but getting error "**Fruitpdf cannot be null**" while executing sql statement.

```
INSERT INTO Fruitbox (Fruitname, Fruitpdf, Fruitprice) VALUES ('Mango', LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\mango.pdf'), '100');
```

Where I am wrong ? Any help is much appreciated. Thanking you

Comment: You should start by reading the requirements for `LOAD_FILE()`... [_"If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, **the function returns `NULL`**"_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

Comment: ok I went through this link but could not find solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575836/insert-a-blob-value-into-mysql-database

Comment: @Phil ok I am reading ur mentioned link

Answer (score 1):

MySQL treats a backslash in a string as an escape character.  You need to use a double backslash :

LOAD_FILE('C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\mango.pdf')

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Edit :
If it still doesn't work :

- Is the file on the MySQL server ?
- Is the 'secure_file_priv' variable    set ? (**SHOW VARIABLES LIKE
  'secure_file_priv';**)  If so, you will need    to place the file under
  that directory.
- Does your user have the FILE privilege ?

Comment: I am getting that error still...is there any wrong in my syntax ?

Comment: @Tom, see update to answer.  The syntax is ok, but it would be better to change the '100' string to 100 as the target column wants an int.